# VS 2017 Extension - Add custom Solution Menu item

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vs-extensibility

I am trying to add a menu item in the solution context menu. So when I do right click on the solution node I want to add a menu item. When I am clicking on the menu item I want to parse all the projects and do some checks.

I am adding the menu but into the toolbar:

```
    private SecondCommand(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
    {
        this.package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
        commandService = commandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

        var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
        var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
        commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
    }
```

How can I access to the solution context menu? The comandService is the VS main toolbar.

Comment: You should edit your question: 1) when you right-click on the solution node, you don't add a menu item, the menu item should be already added. 2) Your code doesn't show that the command is added to the toolbar (or to the context menu), that is done in the .vsct file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my [CommandSolutionContextMenu](https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples) sample